# How to read doc and docx in java

Tags: java, android, apache-poi

First you should know I have looked into many questions and none of them helped me.
I want to be able to read doc and docx documents (when I say read I mean the simplest thing, reading TEXT ONLY).
I saw some posts about poi and scratchpad but I couldn't make it work properly, and most of the times eclipse couldn't even build my project...

Can someone give me a code sample for doc and docx and give me the names (or links) of all the jars I need to use?

Thanks!

Basically this is the code:

```
try {
    if (getFileExtention(path).equals("docx")) {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);
        XWPFWordExtractor oleTextExtractor =
            new XWPFWordExtractor(new XWPFDocument(fis));
        return oleTextExtractor.getText();
    } else if (getFileExtention(path).equals("doc")) {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);
        WordExtractor we = new WordExtractor(fis);
        return we.getText();
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}


return "";
```

I have the following jars:

dom4j-1.6.1.jar

poi-3.8-20120326.jar

poi-ooxml-3.8-20120326.jar

poi-scratchpad-3.8-20120326.jar

xmlbeans-xmlpublic-2.4.0.jar

I have the following problems:

This one occurs many times during build

```
> [2012-07-05 14:12:53 - iCards] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses
> attribute for an anonymous inner class
> (org.dom4j.xpath.DefaultXPath$1) that doesn't come with an associated
> EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
> compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The
> recommended solution is to recompile the class from source, using an
> up-to-date compiler and without specifying any "-target" type options.
> The consequence of ignoring this warning is that reflective operations
> on this class will incorrectly indicate that it is *not* an inner
> class.
```

Another one: (When trying to read docx)

```
> 07-05 14:17:13.245: W/System.err(4339): java.io.IOException: read
> failed: EBADF (Bad file number) 07-05 14:17:13.255:
> W/System.err(4339):   at libcore.io.IoBridge.read(IoBridge.java:432)
> 07-05 14:17:13.260: W/System.err(4339):   at
> java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:179) 07-05
> 14:17:13.265: W/System.err(4339):     at
> java.io.PushbackInputStream.read(PushbackInputStream.java:196) 07-05
> 14:17:13.270: W/System.err(4339):     at
> libcore.io.Streams.readFully(Streams.java:81) 07-05 14:17:13.275:
> W/System.err(4339):   at
> java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.getNextEntry(ZipInputStream.java:230)
> 07-05 14:17:13.280: W/System.err(4339):   at
> org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.<init>(ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.java:51)
> 07-05 14:17:13.285: W/System.err(4339):   at
> org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:83)
> 07-05 14:17:13.290: W/System.err(4339):   at
> org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:228)
> 07-05 14:17:13.295: W/System.err(4339):   at
> org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:39) 07-05
> 14:17:13.300: W/System.err(4339):     at
> org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.<init>(XWPFDocument.java:120)
> 07-05 14:17:13.305: W/System.err(4339):   at
> com.ronEven.iCards.AddRemove.loadFile(AddRemove.java:504) 07-05
> 14:17:13.310: W/System.err(4339):     at
> com.ronEven.iCards.AddRemove.showDoc(AddRemove.java:495) 07-05
> 14:17:13.315: W/System.err(4339):     at
> com.ronEven.iCards.AddRemove.setFilePath(AddRemove.java:492) 07-05
> 14:17:13.320: W/System.err(4339):     at
> com.ronEven.iCards.FileDialog$1.onClick(FileDialog.java:177) 07-05
> 14:17:13.325: W/System.err(4339):     at
> android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3591) 07-05 14:17:13.330:
> W/System.err(4339):   at
> android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14263) 07-05
> 14:17:13.335: W/System.err(4339):     at
> android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605) 07-05
> 14:17:13.340: W/System.err(4339):     at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 07-05
> 14:17:13.345: W/System.err(4339):     at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 07-05 14:17:13.345:
> W/System.err(4339):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507) 07-05
> 14:17:13.345: W/System.err(4339):     at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 07-05
> 14:17:13.350: W/System.err(4339):     at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 07-05 14:17:13.350:
> W/System.err(4339):   at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
> 07-05 14:17:13.350: W/System.err(4339):   at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557) 07-05
> 14:17:13.350: W/System.err(4339):     at
> dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 07-05 14:17:13.355:
> W/System.err(4339): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: read failed:
> EBADF (Bad file number) 07-05 14:17:13.360: W/System.err(4339):   at
> libcore.io.Posix.readBytes(Native Method) 07-05 14:17:13.360:
> W/System.err(4339):   at libcore.io.Posix.read(Posix.java:118) 07-05
> 14:17:13.360: W/System.err(4339):     at
> libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.read(BlockGuardOs.java:149) 07-05
> 14:17:13.360: W/System.err(4339):     at
> libcore.io.IoBridge.read(IoBridge.java:422) 07-05 14:17:13.365:
> W/System.err(4339):   ... 24 more
```

And last one when trying to read doc

```
    07-05 14:17:37.015: W/System.err(4339): java.io.IOException: read failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
07-05 14:17:37.020: W/System.err(4339):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.read(IoBridge.java:432)
07-05 14:17:37.025: W/System.err(4339):     at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:179)
07-05 14:17:37.055: W/System.err(4339):     at java.io.PushbackInputStream.read(PushbackInputStream.java:196)
07-05 14:17:37.055: W/System.err(4339):     at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:163)
07-05 14:17:37.060: W/System.err(4339):     at org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocumentCore.verifyAndBuildPOIFS(HWPFDocumentCore.java:95)
07-05 14:17:37.065: W/System.err(4339):     at org.apache.poi.hwpf.extractor.WordExtractor.<init>(WordExtractor.java:53)
07-05 14:17:37.070: W/System.err(4339):     at com.ronEven.iCards.AddRemove.loadFile(AddRemove.java:509)
07-05 14:17:37.075: W/System.err(4339):     at com.ronEven.iCards.AddRemove.showDoc(AddRemove.java:495)
07-05 14:17:37.085: W/System.err(4339):     at com.ronEven.iCards.AddRemove.setFilePath(AddRemove.java:492)
07-05 14:17:37.090: W/System.err(4339):     at com.ronEven.iCards.FileDialog$1.onClick(FileDialog.java:177)
07-05 14:17:37.095: W/System.err(4339):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3591)
07-05 14:17:37.100: W/System.err(4339):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14263)
07-05 14:17:37.105: W/System.err(4339):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
07-05 14:17:37.110: W/System.err(4339):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-05 14:17:37.115: W/System.err(4339):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-05 14:17:37.120: W/System.err(4339):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
07-05 14:17:37.120: W/System.err(4339):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-05 14:17:37.125: W/System.err(4339):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-05 14:17:37.125: W/System.err(4339):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
07-05 14:17:37.130: W/System.err(4339):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
07-05 14:17:37.130: W/System.err(4339):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-05 14:17:37.130: W/System.err(4339): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: read failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
07-05 14:17:37.150: W/System.err(4339):     at libcore.io.Posix.readBytes(Native Method)
07-05 14:17:37.160: W/System.err(4339):     at libcore.io.Posix.read(Posix.java:118)
07-05 14:17:37.160: W/System.err(4339):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.read(BlockGuardOs.java:149)
07-05 14:17:37.160: W/System.err(4339):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.read(IoBridge.java:422)
07-05 14:17:37.165: W/System.err(4339):     ... 20 more
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have so far?

Comment: @Ron: I'm pretty sure the POI documentation contains everything you asked for. Unless you have a *specific* problem and you *show* what the problem is (and how you tried to solve it), this question is not answerable without copying the documentation/tutorials you already read.

Comment: POI is a perfectly mature library. If you can't make it build or run, you should ask questions more specific to POI and/or Eclipse.

Comment: Yes, Apache POI is the library..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) supports Microsoft Office format as well as many others formats, it provides you with a common interface for all the formats as well as hiding the complexity of maintaining and learning how to use lots of different libraries. It is as easy as calling this [function](http://tika.apache.org/1.1/api/org/apache/tika/Tika.html#parse%28java.io.InputStream,%20org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata%29). You could also use the [Office Parser](http://tika.apache.org/1.1/api/org/apache/tika/parser/microsoft/OfficeParser.html) and [OOXMLParser](http://tika.apache.org/1.1/api/org/apache/tika/parser/microsoft/ooxml/OOXMLParser.html) directly.

Comment: Incorrect - Tika parses .docx files just fine! See the [supported formats page](http://tika.apache.org/1.1/formats.html#Microsoft_Office_document_formats) for details of what's covered, but I can assure you that .docx is one of the ones supported

Answer (score 0):

You have also very powerful application like [LibreOffice SDK](https://www.google.fr/search?q=libreoffice%20sdk&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3afr%3aofficial&client=firefox-a) (or OpenOffice 3) where you can read and manage documents (like docx) and save them in `.txt` format.

Answer (score 0):

- For reading **DOCX** documents we can use **XWPFWordExtractor** with    **XWPFDocument**.
- For reading **DOC** documents we can use **WordExtractor** with **HWPFDocument**.

You got the code for DOCX documents right:

`XWPFWordExtractor oleTextExtractor = new XWPFWordExtractor(new XWPFDocument(fis));`

But HWPFDocument is missing from your code for DOC documents. Just change this line:

`WordExtractor we = new WordExtractor(fis);`

into this:

`WordExtractor we = new WordExtractor(new HWPFDocument(fis));`

As regards the jar files, only poi-ooxml-schemas-3.8-20120326.jar seems to be missing from your Build Path.